# How to dynamically paint cycle materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, dynamic-paint

I am wondering how you would dynamically paint a cycles material over another cycles material? Basically, interchange the material where the brush touches.I have tried switching between them with the attribute and weight paint but doesn't seem to work.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an image texture that you paint on as a stencil between shaders, and this acts like a layer mask in Photoshop. You can also set up an attribute node and use vertex paint, but the effect there is limited to your geometry.

[image]

Comment: Note that the answer to this question has important implications if you are someone who is interested in working with game engines. Often times game engines will apply specularity or other things to models based on map textures. This saves them having to calculate material properties on the fly because the data is embedded in the map you provide. If you want to make your models "game engine ready" you will want to learn how to blend textures using these sorts of maps.